Foxit comment box does not accept devanagari font
I have installed Foxit on Ubuntu and want to write comments on a file in the Marathi language (Devanagari font). The comments box accepts only a single character. How do I set it for multiple characters?

That would be a question to ask the maker of that software.

How did you install foxit? Is it a snap/flatpak app?
